# How to hide parent container in i3?

Tags: window-manager, i3, container, window, toolbar

I'm using pretty much the standard i3 config and sometimes I press the wrong keys and this extra bar shows up at the top:

[image: screenshot]

I believe it's the "parent container"? How do I hide the bar again? It disappears if I close all windows on that workspace, but reappears once I open a window again. I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require restarting i3.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you've switched to a stacking layout. For example, I have this in my config file:

```
bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split
```

The default is usually **split**. Perhaps you pressed `$mod+s` to switch to stacking. Try `$mod+e` to switch back.

See section 6.3 of the i3 docs: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#manipulating_layout

Comment: Heya, nope sorry. That's not it, unfortunately. :( If I switch between stacking, tabbed and split views, then the `S[` just changes to `T[` or `V[`. But that bar just stays there.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. To clarify, the title bar that say **i3: S[google-chrome]**, is that another Chrome tab or window?

Comment: That extra bar is exactly what I want to get rid of. ;) It's nothing but that bar. No extra window. If I close all other windows, that bar also disappears. And as soon as I open a new window again, it shows up.